# Python match unicode string as unicode

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match a unicode string, such that the unicode will not match the string literal.

```
def validate(username):
    if "admin" in username:
        return False
    else:
        return True

validate(username)
```

If I pass `username="\u0061\u0064\u006d\u0069\u006e"`, it will return False, since it is converting the unicode, and then matching, and `"\u0061\u0064\u006d\u0069\u006e"` is unicode for admin. Is there a way to match before converting? The input is not converted, it starts off as unicode. I have tried using regex, but have not succeeded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 3, there's no longer a distinction between "unicode" and "string". So the string `"\u0061\u0064\u006d\u0069\u006e"` is just a string of the characters `a`, `d`, `m`, `i`, `n`, but using unicode codepoint escape sequences; there's no "conversion" going on here, it is exactly equivalent to entering `"admin"`.

What are you trying to achieve?

Remember that string escape sequences, like `\u0061`, are translated during *parsing* by Python, they never actually end up as part of the string. If, instead,  a user, for example, enters the literal string of characters `\u0061\u0064\u006d\u0069\u006e` into a text form, what you will get, in Python notation, will be a string equivalent to `"\\u0061\\u0064\\u006d\\u0069\\u006e"` (notice the escaped backslashes, to indicate these are literal backslashes and not escape sequences).

Comment: In my example, I am hoping it does returns True. I am trying to make it not match.

Comment: There is no way to make it not match, since the literals `"\u0061\u0064\u006d\u0069\u006e"` and `"admin"` are exactly the same string (or rather, they are different *representations* of the exact same string). Could you give some more broader context for what you want to use this for? E.g. is this for validating user input on a web form? What exactly do you want to avoid, in this broader context?

Comment: yes they are entered from a web form. I am trying to blacklist user inputs, and trying to make the only way by entering input. When I pass it SQL it works fine, but if they enter "admin", I don't want it to work. The problem is python converts the unicode when comparing, and I don't want it to.

Comment: We're getting closer to the root of the issue here. So, to be clear, you want to avoid users entering literally `\u0061\u0064\u006d\u0069\u006e`? Or to enter `admin` in any form? Could you perhaps add an example of the SQL you mention and screenshots of the form with examples of what you do an don't want to work? It's still hard to help you without more details, as I don't really understand what's going on from just this.

Comment: I would like if `\u0061\u0064\u006d\u0069\u006e` gets entered, then it will get translated to `admin`.